# Python invalid syntax with "if" statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I tried this code, but I get a `SyntaxError`:

```
if measured_dec =< 0.523966303045:
    print "WARNING! Object may be below Horizon!"
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your less than or equals operator is the wrong way around, change it to this:

```
if measured_dec <= 0.523966303045:
    print "WARNING! Object may be below Horizon!"
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 0):

The less-than-or-equal operator goes the other direction. It should be `<=` not `=<`

```
if measured_dec <= 0.523966303045:
    print "WARNING! Object may be below Horizon!"
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe that I missed something so simple

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of "=<"

Try using:

```
if measured_dec <= 0.523966303045:
    print "WARNING! Object may be below Horizon!"
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 0):

The less than or equal to operator is like this  '<='.
Try it by changing the statement to the following.

```
if measured_dec =< 0.523966303045:
   print "WARNING! Object may be below Horizon!"
```